# Can I see an EX raid I wasn't invited to?

Tags: pokemon-go

If an EX raid is happening at a gym near me, and I wasn't invited, can I still see it (and just not join)? Or does the gym appear normal to anyone who wasn't invited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some digging, I came across [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6yrp8g/ex_raid_battle_for_mewtwo_bellevue_wa/) with a player's experiences with an EX Raid. It looks like only invited players can see the EX Raid. Everyone else just sees a regular gym.

> Raid started at 6. Only people with ex raid passes can see Mewtwo. The rest see the gym that it was prior.

However, this doesn't mean that those uninvited players can flip the gym's controlling team. From the comments, another user was at the raid and gave his experiences:

> can the others battle the gym though? or something?
>
> I was there, no pass. I couldn't interact with the gym in anyway, clicking it did nothing. It just looked like a blue gym with a Dolphan on top